# Using ID number in accessing a page

Tags: html

I would like to inquire for some ideas about my questions.

I would like to create a project using HTML by which I'd use the ID number of a student, and allow them to check their grades. The first step they'll do is to type their ID number in a specified textbox area and upon entering it, they'll see their grades on the screen.

Comment: There are numerous ways that you can achive this. Do you have any code sample that you started with? what technology do you want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use php and a database. Not HTML. You can append their details to the HTML but the underlying tech will be php and SQL

Comment: I think you mean "a serverside language and a database". PHP and MySQL are only one of the many possible combinations of tools out there. Also, you *could* use local storage to do this with just HTML.

Comment: would you do some demonstration? I'm new in PHP.

Comment: @JaylordLegaspi - it'd take more than a demonstration mate.  Best thing to do is have a look at a couple of tutorials online.  If I post some random code I've used it'd make no sense and might do more harm that good.  There are tons of tutorials about. All of the authors are far better at explaining things that I am too :)